# Fetching Mention Notifications via Bit-bucket API

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-api

I am currently working on a task that involves identifying who has mentioned me in their repositories on Bit-bucket. I understand that Bit-bucket sends out notification emails for such mentions. However, I am interested in pro-grammatically fetching these notifications using the Bit-bucket API.

I've taken the time to research the available API options in the Bit-bucket documentation, but unfortunately, I couldn't find any specific API related to retrieving mention notifications.

In light of this situation, I kindly request your assistance. If anyone has experience or insights into how I can achieve this or if there are any workarounds, I would greatly appreciate your guidance and expertise.

Thank you in advance for your help, and I look forward to your valuable input.

Comment: are you using bitbucket cloud or server?

Comment: Yes, I am using Bitbucket Cloud, but there is no API available to retrieve mentions.